# Explanation of fibonacci like sequence limit solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

So, the task is to find $\lim \limits_{x\to\infty}x_n$, where:
$$x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}}{2}, n\geq3,x_1=a,x_2=b$$

What my teacher did is:

$$2\lambda^2-\lambda-1=0$$
$$(2\lambda+1)(\lambda-1)=0 =>\lambda_1=-\frac{1}{2}\lor\lambda_2=1$$

Since the solutions are real and different, we have:
$$x_n=c_1\lambda_1^n+c_2\lambda_2^n=c_1\big(-\frac{1}{2}\big)^n+c_2$$

for $n=1$: $x_1=a=c_1(-\frac{1}{2})+c2$
for $n=2$: $x_2=b=c_1\frac{1}{4}+c_2$

$c_1=\frac{4}{3}(b-a),c_2=\frac{2b+a}{3};$
$$x_n=(-\frac{1}{2})^n\frac{4}{3}(b-a)+\frac{2b+a}{3}\to\frac{2b+a}{3},n\to\infty$$
Can someone explain me what kind of solution this is? Is there a special name for this so I can examine it? Thank you.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_equation#Structure. What is specific to your question, is that the starting values are not given as explicit numbers but as two general constants.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution:

- We may notice that $y_n = 2x_{n+1}+x_n$ does not really depend on $n$, since:

  $$ y_{n+1} = 2 x_{n+2}+x_{n+1} = (x_{n+1}+x_n)+x_{n+1} = 2 x_{n+1}+x_n = y_n$$
- We may notice that $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a Cauchy sequence for sure, since:
  $$ x_{n+2}-x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n+1}-x_n)$$
- The previous points give:
  $$ 3\cdot \lim_{n\to +\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to +\infty} y_n = y_0 = 2b+a.$$